# What does shorthand operator like (+=) in ruby really does?

Tags: ruby, operators

While I can understand that `x += 1` is equivalent to `x = x + 1`, I'm interested what it does in the background.

I've tried in irb with `x += 1` without first assigning value to x and surely I get an error, it says

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)
```

When I tried checking x value after it errored, it's now a nil value which isn't quite clear when it was assigned, unless it's done by `x += 1` statement.

So, I'm trying to understand how the += does thing as I could not find the documentation for it or it being buried behind the lot of ruby classes. Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: That's not specific to the `+=` operator. With `x = x + 1`, you get the same `NoMethodError` and `x` will be `nil` afterwards.

Comment: As @Stefan already pointed, the behaviour is the same: check here https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#assign

Comment: @iGian thanks for the link, that's the explanation I needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby treats identifiers as a variables if it sees assignment (`=`) even if the assignment fails.

```
irb(main):001:0> a
NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

```
irb(main):002:0> a = 1 if false
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> a
=> nil
irb(main):004:0>
```

Even though `a=1` never executes, `a` gets defaulted to `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

### Analysis

#### Defining our Terms

First of all, `+` and `+=` are methods, not [keywords](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/keywords_rdoc.html) or operators. More accurately, + is defined as [Integer#+](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Integer.html#method-i-2B), while `+=` is syntactic sugar provided by the interpreter as shorthand for a common operation such as incremented assignment.

Secondly, `+=` and related operations are called [abbreviated assignments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment) in Ruby. The full list of supported assignment shorthand items currently include:

```
["+=",
 "-=",
 "*=",
 "/=",
 "%=",
 "**=",
 "&=",
 "|=",
 "^=",
 "<<=",
 ">>=",
 "||=",
 "&&="]
```

The only [non-method operators](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#operator) in Ruby are:

```
["=", "..", "...", "!", "not", "&&", "and", "||", "or", "!=", "!~"]
```

and shorthand assignment operators like `+=` are not user-definable.

#### Defining the Problem

The behavior you're seeing has to do with scope, and how the parser handles block-local variables. Specifically, the Ruby [assignment documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods) says:

> [A] local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs[.]

That means that top-level code such as:

```
x
#=> NameError (undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object)
```

raises a NameError exception because `defined? x #=> nil`. However, the parser auto-instantiates local variables when there's an assignment, so that the following works (sort of), at least in the sense that it doesn't raise NameError:

```
# x is autovivified as nil
x = x + 1
#=> NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)
```

However, nil doesn't have a NilClass#+ method, so you get NoMethodError instead of NameError. This is because:

```
nil.respond_to? :+
#=> false
```

### Solutions

The basic solution is to explicitly ensure your variable exists within the current scope, and that it is not nil. You can do this in a variety of ways, but the simplest thing is just to assign it directly. For example:

```
# assign zero to x unless it's truthy
x ||= 0

# perform incrementing assignment
x += 1
```

Alternatively, you can drop the shorthand and cast the autovivified *x* as an Integer, which *does* have a `:+` method. For example, assuming *x* is currently undefined (e.g. you've restarted irb, or you've set *x* to nil):

```
x = x.to_i + 1
#=> 1
```

Comment: `+` _is_ an operator. Whether it is implemented as a method or not doesn't change that.

Comment: @Stefan Technically, it's all three of the following: a [token](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/parse.y#L1190), an [operator](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/parse.y#L2206), and (in various cases) a method. However, since the documentation [explicitly states](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#operator) that "[m]ost...operators [including unary +] are just method invocation in special form," I think you'll have to take the issue up with the Ruby Core Team or the folks writing the documentation if you disagree with what I cited above.

Comment: I'm referring to your first sentence: _"+ and += are methods, not keywords or operators"_ which says that `+` is not an operator. That's not the same as (paraphrasing the docs) _"operators like + and += are implemented as methods"_.